# Is it possible to use app_offline with Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke, azure-web-app-service

I connected to my Azure Website (reserved) via FTP this evening and uploaded an app_offline.htm file (tried HTML as well) but it isn't causing the application to stop as an app_offline.htm file would in a normal hosting environment.

Is it possible to do this on Azure Websites?

The site is a DotNetNuke site, but I doubt that has anything to do with it (as all of my other sites are based on DNN in normal hosting)

Comment: Well, it looks like after I stopped the service, then brought it back up, the app_offline file is now in effect...

Comment: Chris - I have experienced this as well.  Looks like the file monitors don't work as expected.

Comment: You can post a feature request on http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting if current feature is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad to report that app_offline.htm files now appear to work with Azure sites. I was just able to successfully upload an app_offline.htm file to the /site/wwwroot/ of my site, and disable the application while performing an upgrade for DotNetNuke.

Answer (score 1):

Since stopping the service and bringing it back up worked, you should be able to "touch" the web.config file to get the same effect without going offline for a brief period of time.

Comment: I tried this out, in DNN by resetting the app (which just touches the web.config) and also by renaming the web.config via FTP, didn't seem to have any effect.